# Possibilty of removing MVCBuildViews target from a C# ASP .Net project

Tags: c#, msbuild, msbuild-task, msbuild-4.0

In my C# ASP.Net project that utilizes the CoreXT build system, there's a specific target defined as follows:

`<Target Name="MvcBuildViews" AfterTargets="AfterBuild" Condition="'$(MvcBuildViews)'=='true'"> <AspNetCompiler VirtualPath="temp" PhysicalPath="$(WebProjectOutputDir)" /> </Target>`

When running MSBuild on Azure DevOps, it's necessary to set MvcBuildViews to true in the command line, but doing so results in an error. Removing the above target configuration resolves the error. Since my project exclusively contains API controllers without any views, will removing this target configuration impact the build process in anyway?

Comment: > but doing so results in an error - What error?

Comment: It also seems you should have this target when you have any views, to pre-compile them - https://improveandrepeat.com/2018/11/pre-compile-your-views-in-asp-net-mvc/, so removing it most probably won't affect your project

Comment: @Dice The error I was getting was the below

`(MvcBuildViews target) -> 
           ASPNETCOMPILER : error ASPCONFIG: Could not load file or assembly 'AbcDef' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. [C:\__w\1\s\src\AbcDef\AbcDef.csproj]`

Comment: is AbcDef.csproj your project? What is it used for?